# How is ABV calculated if distilled spirits are added to beer?

Tags: calculations, alcohol-content, bourbon, vodka

How would one calculate the ABV of a beer if distilled spirits were added?  For instance, when making a beer recipe that called for adding bourbon as a flavoring agent.  If you started with, say, 5 US gallons of beer at 5% ABV and you added 1 quart of "80 proof" spirits, how would one calculate the resulting ABV?

Comment: US gallons or imperial gallons?

Comment: Added "US" to question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems like a simple solution dilution problem. Take

```
5 gallons = 20 quarts => 20 quarts * 5% ABV = 1 quart alcohol.
```

Then take your 1 quart of "80 proof" (40% ABV), and we get

```
1 quart * 0.4 = 0.4 quarts alcohol
```

So we have a total volume of 21 quarts (beer plus spirits) and a total of 1.4 quarts alcohol, thus

```
1.4 / 21 = 6.67% ABV
```

Unless I'm missing something about ABV percentage, `6.67%` should be the final answer.

In general, if we have (making sure we are using consistent units)

```
O - the original volume, in quarts
A - the volume of spirits to add, in quarts
s - the % ABV of the original volume
p - the % ABV of the spirits
```

Then we can use the general formula below

```
((O * s) + (A * p)) / (O + A)
```

Comment: Is that a US gallon or an imperial gallon?

Comment: US gallon, but the idea is the same, get the total alcohol in each fluid, and combine

Comment: Just clarifying since these differences can cause issues sometimes. (For instance 40% ABV is 80 proof in the US but 40% ABV in the UK is 70 proof.) I should have realised though that it's a matter of ratio the units in use are slightly irrelevant.

Comment: @pharap Indeed, this type of problem is a basic homework problem in university physics 1. The units don't matter as much as the method.

Comment: Sadly we don't all study mathematics or sciences at uni level. The maths I do these days doesn't tend to use actual units (except maybe time units, or if a pixel counts as a unit).

Comment: I can add a general equation later. It might serve the homebrew community as a whole

Comment: Not part of the original question, but perhaps a comment on how a hydrometer reading would work or not work after addition of spirits would be helpful.  Or maybe that would be a separate question.

Comment: @dale that would probably work better as a separate question. I'm not really sure how that might be done